# Wkwebview not working in ios 12 and application gets crashed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webkit, wkwebview

I am working on wkwebview and testing my app in ios 12 but it's not working. I saw many stack-overflow solutions but still not working,
Following is the error:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration() Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
```

this statement is written in loadView(). It's working fine in IOS 14 and above. But not working on IOS below that version.

I have also added webkit.framework in **Framework, library & embed content** even restarted my xcode and simulator.
Cleaned my simulator as well

Comment: I have the same exact statement in my code, and it works on iOS 12-14. So maybe it's more about where this statement is or how you initialize your WKWebView. With information provided, that's unclear. Also I find it weird that you need to add "webkit.framework in Framework, library & embed content" - that shouldn't be the case normally.

Comment: I added this statement in loadView() where i am creating my webview and assigning it to my view

Comment: I used same syntax as https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview and it's working fine for IOS 14